# Passing comma seperated parameter values through Oracle SOAP request

Tags: oracle, soap, bi-publisher

I running a BI Publisher report through SOAP request. the BI Publisher data model contain the following condition :

WHERE PERIOD_NAME IN  ( :P_PERIOD_NAME )

when i pass single period like "Jan-21" it works fine but then when i pass "Jan-21, Feb-21" it fails.

how to pass comma separated values ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a single string (that happens to contain commas) and not a comma-separated list of multiple values so your query is effectively:

```sql
WHERE period_name IN ( 'Jan-21, Feb-21' )
```

Instead, surround both the delimited list and the list item in delimiters (so that you do not get a partial match) and then match on the substring:

```sql
WHERE ', ' || :P_PERIOD_NAME || ', ' LIKE '%, ' || period_name || ', %'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac0322ae631f7a323d45c02ffa224410)*

Comment: Where to add this ? in the data model ?

Comment: Where did you have the previous `WHERE` expression? You tagged the question as Oracle so I gave an Oracle solution.

Comment: The SQL failed when changing the following from:
WHERE PERIOD_NAME IN ( :P_PERIOD_NAME )
to
WHERE ', ' || :P_PERIOD_NAME || ', ' LIKE '%, ' || period_name || ', %'

Comment: moreover the question is tagged as both "SOAP" and "Oracle" and i prefer to modify the SOAP request to accept comma separated parameter values

Comment: What does "failed" mean? The query works in Oracle [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac0322ae631f7a323d45c02ffa224410). Also, if you are looking for a specific type of solution then you sould make that explicit in your question and edit your question to include a [MRE] with sufficient detail to replicate your SOAP data/models/setup etc. rather than giving half the information.

Answer (score 0):

Let try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE 1=1
AND PERIOD_NAME IN (
select regexp_substr('Jan-21,Feb-21','[^,]+', 1, level) as period from dual
connect by regexp_substr('Jan-21,Feb-21', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
);
```

Comment: Hi,
My BI Publisher data model is :
SELECT 
PERIOD_NAME
FROM
GL_PERIODS
WHERE 1 = 1
AND PERIOD_NAME IN  (:P_GL_PERIOD_NAME )

Comment: Hi Shlomo, 

Based on my example you can change the model accordingly

Comment: SELECT PERIOD_NAME 
FROM GL_PERIODS 
WHERE 1 = 1 
AND PERIOD_NAME IN (
select regexp_substr(:P_GL_PERIOD_NAME,'[^,]+', 1, level) as period from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:P_GL_PERIOD_NAME, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
);

Comment: It works only for one period value. but when selecting more then one period i get

oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Can you try with parameter 'Jan-21,Feb-21' it's haven't space in comma seperated

Comment: The following :
SELECT PERIOD_NAME FROM GL_PERIODS WHERE 1 = 1 AND PERIOD_NAME IN ( select regexp_substr('Jan-21,Feb-21','[^,]+', 1, level) as period from dual connect by regexp_substr('Jan-21,Feb-21', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null )

return
Jan-21
Feb-21

Comment: I see it as duplicate data, can use DISTINCT to remove duplicate.

Comment: So it's ok or not? any issue from there?

Comment: Can you tell how to change your original query to accept it with space ?  
'Jan-21, Feb-21' ? because this is the way the BI Publisher convert the user parameter selection

Comment: Suggest using TRIM to remove space in a string.

Comment: SELECT PERIOD_NAME 
FROM GL_PERIODS 
WHERE 1 = 1 
AND PERIOD_NAME IN (
 SELECT TRIM(PERIOD)
 FROM
 (
  select regexp_substr(:P_GL_PERIOD_NAME,'[^,]+', 1, level) as period from dual
  connect by regexp_substr(:P_GL_PERIOD_NAME, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
 )
);

Comment: Still not. the way BI Publisher convert the parameter input into XML tag is :
P_GL_PERIOD_NAME ([Feb-21,Jan-21])

so i guess there is need to remove also the [ ]

Comment: You can remove character ([]) with function REPLACE

Comment: SELECT PERIOD_NAME FROM GL_PERIODS WHERE 1 = 1 
AND   period_set_name   = 'OTI Calendar'
AND PERIOD_NAME IN ( SELECT TRIM(PERIOD) FROM ( select regexp_substr(REPLACE(REPLACE(:P_GL_PERIOD_NAME,'['),']'),'[^,]+', 1, level) as period from dual connect by regexp_substr(REPLACE(REPLACE(:P_GL_PERIOD_NAME,'['),']'), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null ) )